# Electron Builder In Linux - Failed to load resource

Tags: linux, electron, electron-builder, deb, electron-packager

I am trying to create a distributable application using electron-builder for my Electron app. However, I am facing a problem where if I use electron-packager ( "build": "electron-packager ." ), I am able to create the application without any issues and it runs fine. But if I use electron-builder ( "dist": "electron-builder --linux" ), the generated .deb file installs successfully, but when I try to open the application, I get the following error:

'app.js:1 to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND'

I have provided some information below about the contents of my files. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'" />
    <title>Machine UI</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="machine-ui"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="./build/js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

webpack.common.js :

```
    const path = require("path");
    const webpack = require("webpack");
    
    module.exports = {
      mode: "development",
      entry: "./src/index.js",
      devtool: "inline-source-map",
      target: "electron-renderer",
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader",
              options: {
                presets: [
                  [
                    "@babel/preset-env",
                    {
                      targets: {
                        esmodules: true,
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                  "@babel/preset-react",
                ],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico|webp)$/i,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "file-loader",
                options: {
                  outputPath: "images",
                  name: "[name].[ext]",
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
          options: {
            postcss: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
          },
        }),
      ],
      resolve: {
        extensions: [".js"],
      },
      output: {
        filename: "app.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build", "js"),
      },
    };
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "machineui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.common.js --watch",
    "build": "electron-packager .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder --linux"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "Your Name",
    "email": "youremail@example.com"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/*********",
  "license": "MIT",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.example.machineui",
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "deb",
        "snap",
        "rpm"
      ],
      "category": "Utility",
      "maintainer": "Osman Talha"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "electron": "^24.1.1",
    "electron-builder": "^24.2.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.16",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "electron-packager": "^17.1.1",
    "electron-reload": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "eleectron": "^0.0.1-security",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.1.0",
    "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^8.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-animated-popup": "^0.1.8",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-move": "^6.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-simple-keyboard": "^3.5.55",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "react-wavify": "^1.8.0",
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.9",
    "webpack": "^5.77.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```